# How to give custom icons on expand and collapse of Tree Component in AntD for react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to replace the right and down arrow of Tree Component to Up and Down arrows when a node is expanded and collapsed respectively. Either Expand or collapse icon is changing when Iam using switcherIcon property. But I would like to change both for expanded and collapsed state. Any leads would be helpful.